# Twofish Encryption

Tags: encryption

I know AES Encryption supports 128,192,256 bit encryptions. ANy idea how many bits is twofish encryption. Is it also similarly flexible in bit lengths. I searched net but couldnt get conclusive answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How much searching did you do exactly? The [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twofish) has this information, which is the first result from google when you use the keyword "Twofish"

The keysizes for twofish are: 128, 192, 256 bit.  The block size is 128 bit.

Answer (score 2):

From the [Twofish web page](http://www.schneier.com/twofish.html):

> Twofish has a 128-bit block size, a key size ranging from 128 to 256 bits, and is optimized for 32-bit CPUs.

So 128, 192, and 256 bit keys would all be valid for Twofish.